# How to use multiple columns in whereIn statement?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have entity:

```
@Entity({
  name: 'test_table'
})
export class SomeEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: 'int4',
    name: 'id'
  })
  id: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'int2',
    name: 'some_column_1'
  })
  someColumn1: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'some_column_2'
  })
  someColumn2: string;
}
```

Now i need to create this query:

```
select id, some_column_1, some_column_2 from test_table where (some_column_1, some_column_2) in ( (1, 'test1'), (2, 'test2') )
```

For this query i try to:

```
//.......
.where("(some_column_1, some_column_2) IN (:...arr)", {
  arr: [
    [1, 'test1'],
    [2, 'test2']
  ]
})
.getMany();
```

And i get Error: 
`input of anonymous composite types is not implemented`

How to create this query in typeorm?

Database is postgres

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the tuple as parameter like `IN(:arr)` you should build the sql on your own. For example:

```
const inTuples = items.map(item => `(${item.column1}, ${item.column2})`).join(",")
const result = await demoRepo.createQueryBuilder("demo")
   .where(`(demo.column1, demo.column2) IN (${inTuples})`)
   .getMany()
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to rebuild your query in one statement, but the following should work:

```
const arr = [
 [1, 'test1'],
 [2, 'test2']
];
queryBuilder.where('some_column_1 IN(:arr)', { arr: arr });
queryBuilder.andWhere('some_column_2 IN(:arr)', { arr: arr });
queryBuilder.getMany();
```

Comment: no, this folowing return something like this: select id, some_column_1, some_column_2 from test_table where `some_column_1` in (1,2) AND `some_column_2` in ('test1','test2'). So if in db i will have: 1_test1, 2_test2, 1_test2. This query will return all three rows, but i need only 1st and 2nd row